# How to run particular (out of build cycle) Junit5 tests using Gradle

Tags: gradle, junit5

I am moving tests to junit5 that are going to be run with Gradle. In a project I work with there are unit tests and some specific tests that must be run on demand (from particular Gradle tasks I suppose).

It is clear about unit tests. Gradle plugin adds a support for that. 
But I could not find a way to define another test task for my needs 
I searched in Junit5 plugin source and found out that there are no any particular class for that purpose. The Gradle plugin simply sets up a JavaExec task and then runs it.

Therefore it seem that there are no visible ways to define my own task of 
the built-in type like this

> task myTask(type: Junit5TestRunner) 
>     Here we set up a task

Any ideas how it can be done ?

Answer (score 2):

Define a new configuration, depend on `junit-platform-console-standalone` artifact and configure the console launcher to your needs. Like:

```
configurations {
    standalone
}

dependencies {
    standalone 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console-standalone:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

task downloadJUnitPlatformStandalone(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.standalone
    into "$buildDir/junit-platform-standalone"
    eachFile { println " (standalone) -> " + it.file.name }
}

task runJUnitPlatformStandalone(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: downloadJUnitPlatformStandalone) {
    jvmArgs '-ea'
    jvmArgs '-Djava.util.logging.config.file=src/test/logging.properties'
    classpath = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/junit-platform-standalone", include: '*.jar') + project.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    main 'org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher'
    args += '--scan-class-path'
    args += '--disable-ansi-colors'
    args += '--details=tree'
    args += "--reports-dir=$project.testReportDir"
}

test.dependsOn runJUnitPlatformStandalone
```

Source [junit-platform-standalone.gradle](https://github.com/sormuras/beethoven/blob/master/gradle/junit-platform-standalone.gradle) or alternate (Jupiter-only) dependencies [jupiter.gradle](https://github.com/sormuras/beethoven/blob/master/gradle/jupiter.gradle).

Without own configuration and download: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/junit-5-jupiter-platform-snapshot-console-launcher-task/19773/2

Comment: Well. Thanks I will try.

Comment: What is the purpose of downloadJUnitPlatformStandalone.  May I reference to local library and not to copy ?

Comment: It downloads (copies) the dependency(ies) from configured Maven repos.

Comment: The `classpath = ...` option is the place where you may reference local libraries and/or your compiled test classes.

Comment: You can re-use your existing (downloaded/provided) dependencies via: Without own configuration and download: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/junit-5-jupiter-platform-snapshot-console-launcher-task/19773/2

Answer (score 0):

it seems like I found a bit better decision for that task

> > task myTask(type: Junit5TestRunner) Here we set up a task

Sormuras' answer gave me certainly a right direction
The solution is to move the most boilerplate code into separate task class and then use that task from script and therefore make it more reusable.

the class

```groovy
/**
 *
 * Created by Vladimir Bogodkhov on 21/04/17.
 * @author Vladimir Bogodkhov
 */
class SQJUnit5 extends JavaExec {

    enum Details {

        /**
         * No test plan execution details are printed.
         */
        none("none"),

        /**
         * Test plan execution details are rendered in a flat, line-by-line mode.
         */
        flat("flat"),

        /**
         * Test plan execution details are rendered as a simple tree.
         */
        tree("tree"),

        /**
         * Combines tree flat modes.
         */
        verbose("verbose");

        Details(String id) {
            this.id = Objects.requireNonNull(id);
        }

        final String id

    }


    List<String> includeTags
    List<String> excludeTags
    List<String> includeTests = ['^.*Tests?$']
    List<String> excludeTests
    File reportsdir
    Details details = Details.none;
    List<String> scanclasspath


    SQJUnit5() {
        jvmArgs '-ea'
        main 'org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher'
        args += '--disable-ansi-colors'
        args += '--details=tree'
        args += '--details-theme=unicode'
    }

    @Override
    void exec() {
        prepare()
        super.exec()
    }

    private void prepare() {
        if (includeTags) includeTags.each { args += ['--include-tag', it] }
        if (excludeTags) excludeTags.each { args += ['--exclude-tag', it] }
        if (includeTests) includeTests.each { args += ['--include-classname', it] }
        if (excludeTests) excludeTests.each { args += ['--exclude-classname', it] }
        if (reportsdir) {
            if (reportsdir.exists() && !reportsdir.isDirectory()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("reportsdir must be a directory. $reportsdir.absolutePath")
            }
            args += ['--reports-dir', reportsdir.absolutePath]
        }

        if (!scanclasspath) {
            args += ['--scan-class-path']
        } else {
            scanclasspath.each { args += ['--scan-class-path', it] }
        }
    }
}
```

Script snippet

```groovy
task particularTests(type: SQJUnit5, dependsOn: build) {
    classpath = project.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath + fileTree(dir: '../../libs/junit5', include: '*.jar')

    excludeTags = ['DebugRun']// optional param
    includeTests = ['^.*Check$', '^.*Probe$']// optional param
    details = SQJUnit5.Details.verbose // optional param
    reportsdir = file('build/testReportDir') // optional param
}
```

Now junit5 tests can be used as a usual Gradle task.