# Allure report is empty when use Allure2+Junit5+Gradle+Selenide

Tags: gradle, allure, junit5

My build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
apply plugin: 'io.qameta.allure'

defaultTasks 'clean', 'test'

ext.junitJupiterVersion = '5.0.0-M4'
ext.selenideVersion = '4.4.3'

compileTestJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs += "-parameters"
}

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M4'
        classpath 'io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.3'
    }
}

  allure {
    aspectjweaver = true
    autoconfigure = true
    version = '2.1.1'
}

  configurations {
    agent
  }

  dependencies {
    // JUnit5
    compile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    compile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")

    // Selenide
    compile("com.codeborne:selenide:${selenideVersion}") {
        exclude group: 'junit'
    }

    // Allure
    agent 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.10'
    compile 'ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-junit-adaptor:1.4.23'
    compile 'io.qameta.allure:allure-junit5:2.0-BETA6'
}

    junitPlatform {
platformVersion = "1.0.0-M5"
enableStandardTestTask = true
}

task runJupiter(type: JavaExec) {
jvmArgs '-ea'
jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.agent.singleFile}"
classpath = project.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
main 'org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher'
args '--scan-class-path'
args "--reports-dir=${buildDir}/allure-results"

finalizedBy 'allureReport'
}

test.dependsOn runJupiter
```

Tests are finished successfully and three folders are created automatically:

> {projectDir}\allure-results  with .json file
>
> {projectDir}\build\test-results\junit-platform  with TEST-junit-jupiter.xml file
>
> {projectDir}\build\reports\allure-report

I tried to open .json and .xml result locally via allure command line (CLI).  The allure report is opened but it is blank:
[this is a report view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ta7J.jpg)

I suppose my mistake in gradle dependencies. I quite confused which libraries and versions should be used for JUnit5+Allure2+Gradle+Selenide+Java8?

Comment: What Allure command line command are you using to view the report?

Answer (score 1):

The JUnit Platform Gradle plugin does currently not use the `test` task (it needs changes in Gradle core in order to do so). Thus, things like `test.doFirst {...}` are not going to work.

Instead of using the plugin, you should be able to create your own task that runs the `ConsoleLauncher` and add the JVM agent there. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43512503/6327046 for an example.

Comment: Which Gradle plugin are you referring to in your first sentence?

Comment: It works for me. Thank you very much. I wrote this: tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    if (it.name == 'junitPlatformTest') {
        doFirst {
            jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.agent.singleFile}"
        }
        finalizedBy 'allureReport'
    }