# How to write a Java integration test task in Gradle with JUnit5?

Tags: java, gradle, junit5

With Junit4, I had the following definition of integration test:

```
task testIntegration(type: Test, dependsOn: jar) {
    group 'Verification'
    description 'Runs the integration tests.'
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.testInt.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.testInt.runtimeClasspath
    systemProperties['jar.path'] = jar.archivePath
}
```

However, with JUnit5, this does not work anymore. I am not being able to figure what to change (it's too late). Any hints?

I am using the `junit-platform-gradle-plugin`.

Comment: JUnit5 only defines a task for the `main` source set. You can see a request at [junit-team/junit5-samples](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/issues/35) for this kind of support. You will need a new task to run JUnit. You can see an example of how you could possibly set it up in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512165/how-to-run-particular-out-of-build-cycle-junit5-tests-using-gradle/43512503#43512503). I don't think the JUnit team plans on supporting it and is waiting for [the Gradle team](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1037) to build in native support.

Comment: @mkobit I am aware this is gradle issue. thanx for the link, i think i am almost there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the plugin and calling `ConsoleRunner` directly:

```
task testIntegration(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: jar) {
    group 'Verification'
    description 'Runs the integration tests.'

    dependencies {
        testRuntime lib.junit5_console
    }

    classpath = sourceSets.testInt.runtimeClasspath
    systemProperties['jar.path'] = jar.archivePath

    main 'org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher'
    args = ['--scan-classpath', sourceSets.testInt.output.classesDirs.asPath,
            '--reports-dir', "${buildDir}/test-results/testInt"
    ]
}
```

Also, here is how to apply JaCoCo with the settings:

```
afterEvaluate {
    jacoco {
        applyTo testUnit
        applyTo testIntegration
    }
    testIntegration.extensions.getByName("jacoco").excludes = ['*Test*', '*.?', '*Foo*', 'jodd.asm5.*', '*.fixtures.*']
}
```

FOr more details check [Jodds build file](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/blob/master/build.gradle)